# Deploying website, error points to file on local pc, using Visual Studio 2012

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I've created a website in Visual Studio 2012, now when I upload my files to the web server I receive an error whereby the system cannot find the file specified.

It seems to only happen on files which fetch data from a database.

I've tested my connection string and that seems to be working as I've close the connection as well as deleted the local db I was using. My site works fine when run locally, but the second I try access it online I get the same error.

Link to error image:- https://i.stack.imgur.com/PtzoW.jpg

I've highlighted the error that puzzles me in the image. It keeps trying to find the file on my local pc it seems. I've searched through my code and can't seem to find anything that is hard coded.

Your help is much appreciated, hopefully someone has encountered and solved this problem.

Comment: The website is umdabu.co.za

The only pages that work so far hen live are http://www.umdabu.co.za/about.aspx and http://www.umdabu.co.za/contact.aspx

These two pages do not require database access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The possible reason are,

1. The folder which containing specified file is may be read only or admin access or hidden in server machine. If possible, check the folder properties.
2. Make sure the file containing folder has uploaded or not on server.
3. It won't find your local pc if you hosted on other IP(server). The same root folder may be present on server side, so don't get confuse with server and local machine.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.
I've changed all the permissions and it seems to be fine.
Re-uploaded the files to the server for good measure.
Just a question, why would it be looking on my local pc for the file? And not just in the root directory?

Comment: Once files have been moved to server. Then no need to talk about local pc for online purpose. Because your files will run from the server not from your local pc. As you suggested, it's not looking in your local pc. For more clarification check here [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd394698(v=vs.110).aspx]

Answer (score 0):

The "file not found" error is actually misleading, the error you need to deal with is the `SqlException` error and indicates the connection string is wrong - you need to update the connection string to access the SQL Server externally.

Are you also deploying the database to another server or are you attempting to access the same database as when testing locally?  If you are accessing the same database locally, make sure the web server you are using to host the website can actually access the SQL Server on your local machine - check all firewalls and other things, and make sure that the SQL Server accepts TCP connections.